# Making iframe and footer play nice

Tags: html, css, iframe, footer

I have a Typeform survey that I am embedding into a webpage. However, a footer is required to be shown at all parts of the website so I have added a `<footer>` block below the `<iframe>`.

After much tweaking however, the site has gotten worse and worse in the sense that the scrollbar for the iframe no longer seems stay within the window (hence my `<body style="height: 90%; width: 99%">`), and everything seems to be pushed to the right.

The page can be found at: http://testbed103012030.azurewebsites.net/

The site content is:

```
   <body style="height: 90%; width: 99%">
      <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" class="frame"><iframe id="typeform-full" src="https://showroom.typeform.com/to/WJ565l" 
         frameborder="0"></iframe></div>
      <footer>
         <div class="footer">
            <p>
               Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit | sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua | &copy; 2015 Lorem Ipsum
            </p>
            <p>
               <i>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident</i>
            </p>
         </div>
      </footer>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="embed.js"></script>
   </body>
```

And the CSS is:

```
  <style type="text/css">
     html{
     margin: 0;
     height: 100%;
     overflow: hidden;
     }
     iframe{
     position: relative;
     left:0;
     right:0;
     bottom:0;
     top:0;
     border:0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     }
     .footer{
     position: relative;
     width: 100%;
     bottom: 0;
     right: 0;
     left: 0;
     height: auto;
     background: white;
     font-family: "Source Sans Pro",sans-serif;
     text-align: center;
     font-size: 80%;
     }
  </style>
```

How do I:

1. Make sure the site consists of the iframe at the top and footer at
   the bottom
2. Where the footer does not cover the iframe in any way
3. Where the iframe Typeform still displays optimally
4. And the entire website displays well on mobile devices
5. And if possible, that the whole footer is shown 100% of the time (right now in my example screenshot I have to scroll down to see the last line)

[image: screenshot from mobile browser]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a little of the CSS calc function:

```
<body style="height: 100%; width: 99%">
    <div style="width: 100%; height: calc(100% - 7em);" class="frame">
        <iframe id="typeform-full" src="https://showroom.typeform.com/to/WJ565l" 
         frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
    <footer style="height: 7em">
    </footer>
</body>
```

Also pro tip: Take out the inline styles and switch them to classes in the stylesheet.

Comment: That worked for the footer, thanks! Sorry about the inline styles, they're mostly there for testing at this point.

Comment: Thanks @ReignOfComputer, please checkmark my solution